# SWIFT IOS return 2 different objects in a same function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, return, afnetworking

I want to return request if all went well and return error if something went wrong.

```
func afnwPost(url: String,client_id: String, client_secret:String,grant_type:String, userparam: String, passwordparam:String)-> AnyObject{

    var parameters = ["client_id":client_id,"client_secret":client_secret,"grant_type":grant_type,"username":userparam,"password":passwordparam]

    manager.POST( url,
    parameters: parameters,
    success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
    println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
    return responseObject
    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
    println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    return error
    })
}
```

The call method

```
 var respuesta = obtenerToken.afnwPost(host_oauth,
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret:client_secret,
        grant_type:grant_type_token,
        userparam: textfieldUsuario.text,
        passwordparam: textfieldContrasenya.text)
```

Comment: Take a look at countless examples of the Failable pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return two different objects by using a **Tuple** like that:

```
//Dummy method to show how it works.
func yourFunction()->(responseObject:AnyObject, error:String){
  return (responseObject, error)
}
```

To access them again, do something like that:

```
var yourResult = yourFunction()
println(yourResult.responseObject)
println(yourResult.error)
```

Of course you will have to check, which value is `nil` when you receive the returns of your function.

Comment: To the one who downvoted my answer. Please explain your down-vote. I'd like to know what I've done wrong in my answer.